# how to stop do-while looping and fixing the button function?

Tags: php, loops, mysqli, do-while

I want to make it stop looping, but I dont know what's wrong. I want it to be like..
Clicking the button then shows the text, and keep repeating like that in one page.

I have the code tht goes like this:

```
<?php
    include "koneksi.php";
    $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM buatsoal_db ORDER BY ID DESC");
    $id = mysqli_query($connection, "select 'ID' from buatsoal_db");
    ?>

<?php
    do{ ?>
        <form method= 'post'>
        <input name='next' type='submit' id='next' value='next'>
        </form>
            <?php if(isset($_POST['next'])){ ?>
                    <table width="637" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
                    <tr>
                        <th width="297" scope="col">
                            <?php $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($query);
                             echo $row['SOALTXT']; ?>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
            <?php } 
            ?>
<?php   }

    while ($id = 'S01');
    echo "sudah selesai";
?>
```

I dont know what's wrong, it keeps looping like this :
[first_executes_looping non stops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVht3.jpg)
and the button next shows up all together, and when I clicked it, the txt shows up at the same time too. I want it to shows up one by one, and keeep it repeat until the id="s01"from the txt is over.

Comment: The reason it keeps looping is because `$id = 'S01'` is an assignment which returns the value assigned i.e. `'SO1'` which is true in a boolean context. You need to have a comparison instead i.e. `$id == 'S01'`. However this still won't work as you're not actually fetching values from the `select 'ID' from buatsoal_db` query

Answer (score 1):

Just use the comparison statement in do while loop like:

```
do{
//your code block here
}while($id == 'S01');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is problem with your while condition. single = is used to assign values and == is used to compare. So here you have to use == to compare. Try below code.

```
<?php
    include "koneksi.php";
    $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM buatsoal_db ORDER BY ID DESC");
    $id = mysqli_query($connection, "select 'ID' from buatsoal_db");
    ?>
    <?php
        do{ ?>
            <form method= 'post'>
            <input name='next' type='submit' id='next' value='next'>
            </form>
                <?php if(isset($_POST['next'])){ ?>
                        <table width="637" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
                        <tr>
                            <th width="297" scope="col">
                                <?php $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($query);
                                 echo $row['SOALTXT']; ?>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                <?php } 
                ?>
    <?php   }    
        while ($id == 'S01');
        echo "sudah selesai";
    ?>
```

Comment: ive tried it, and the output is the next line, where id ==s02, and"sudah selesai".  do you know why? because what im looking for is soaltxt where id ==s01.

Comment: You have only fired query you have to fetch data also here 
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "select 'ID' from buatsoal_db");
$query->fetch_assoc();

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in **while** statement.

what you have to do is:

```
do {
...
}
while($id == 'S01');
```

**== is the solution**

Comment: ive changed it, but, do you know why the output is that have id = s02, not s01? and it also execute the  "echo 'sudah selesai'" ?

Comment: as per your comment, id value is s02 and you comparing with s01 then obviously loop will break and next line of code will get executed.